# Docker image from scratch and entrypoint

Tags: python, docker

I need to create a docker image with my flask program as small as possible.
Due to this, I have compiled by pyinstaller my flask program and I want to create a docker image:

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM scratch
COPY ./source/flask /
COPY ./source/libm-2.31.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
ENTRYPOINT ["/flask"]
```

After running container I have error:
standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: no such file or directory

[Source code can be downloaded here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rHbDvJ9YD9QjOmn-TtEcGOY9EzZ672LC/view?usp=sharing)
Please help.

Comment: You are going to need more than this few files to have a working container. To create small images an `alpine` based image is a good starting point.

Comment: A Flask application will typically need at least a Python interpreter, its standard library, and a small set of add-on libraries.  There may be smaller ways to do this than the standard `python` image, but it needs a lot of code.  Using a compiled language like Go or Rust for this could get you a working `FROM scratch` static-binary setup, if saving bytes is critical.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by @BMitch, `scratch` is not even a minimal image, it is a pseudo-image containing nothing. An empty directory comes as a close resemblance. It is useful when your application is a single binary or in case you want to build your own [Linux from scratch](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/).

Since your application is written in `python`, it requires some things you can find in an operating system, like interpreter for example. Therefore, unless you want to spend weeks building everything from scratch, it will be better to use a regular Linux OS image. Pick `debian`, `ubuntu` or `centos` and you should be fine with it.

##### Note on Alpine images

There are also `alpine` images, famous for their low size. For now I recommend against using Alpine Linux if you are going to use `pip`. Many packages on PyPI have binary wheels, which significantly speed up building time. Until [PEP 656](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0656/) was accepted (17/Apr/21) there were absolutely no wheels for Alpine Linux, meaning that *every package that you use - you compile from scratch*. This is because Alpine uses `musl` C compiler, while most other Linux distributions `glibc`.

##### What's inside `scratch`

Though by itself there is nothing, there are some things mounted by Docker at runtime. If you are curious what are these things, here is a Dockefile that adds `ls` to the image:

```
FROM busybox as b
FROM scratch
COPY --from=b /bin/ls /bin/ls
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/ls"]
```

Once you've built it, you can use `ls` to explore:

```
❯ docker build . -t scr

❯ docker run --rm scr /
bin
dev
etc
proc
sys

❯ docker run --rm scr /bin
ls

❯ docker run --rm scr /dev
core
fd
full
mqueue
null
ptmx
pts
random
shm
stderr
stdin
stdout
tty
urandom
zero
```

Comment: Slight terminology nit: `scratch` is a pseudo base image containing nothing, so I wouldn't even call it a minimal image. You won't find any layer added to the filesystem from scratch like you would any other base image. All the other files you're seeing in `/dev`, `/etc`, `/proc`, and `/sys` are automatically mounted by docker for any container and weren't part of the image.

Comment: @BMitch Thank you! I knew that at least some of these are added at the runtime but I did not know that all. I've refactored the answer with what you've said. By the way, can you recommend any source where I can learn Docker internals like this? Except for the source code, of course.

Comment: There's a few docs on it, including the [hub readme](https://hub.docker.com/_/scratch) and the [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/baseimages/). I spend a lot of my time working with some [registry tooling](https://github.com/regclient/regclient) so I've gotten very accustomed to what creates a layer by looking at manifests and blobs.

Comment: Perhaps something changed, but when I attempted to run this image with the docker run command, I get exec /bin/ls: no such file or directory. Where makes me think it's getting overwritten by the mounted volumes.